# Excel Conditional Formatting - sum column and colour scale

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting, duration

I have an excel where I need to calculate the sum of duration in every week and highlight the cells in green whose sum is >20hrs and red if sum < 20hrs.
All the values in column B and C are duration (2hrs, 4hrs and so on) and not time.
According to my knowledge Conditional Formatting should work. Could someone please help!

Expected Output

[image]

Thanks:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In cells B1:C6, enter a pair of conditional formats by formula:

- `=B$7>TIMEVALUE("20:00")`
- `=B$7<TIMEVALUE("20:00")`

You'll probably want to change one of your comparisons to `>=` or `<=` to handle the case in which the times add up to exactly 20:00.

Answer (score -1):

Go To Format Condition Use Greater Then And Less Then

Greater Then enter value =20

Less Then  value =20

Comment: When working with date/time values in Excel, a numerical value of 20 means 20 days. 20 hours is 20/24 = 0.833333.

Comment: @jsheeran what could be the better way to get this?